# Add locations to GNOME Search file index

Tags: gnome, files, search, 17.10, tracker

I have a SSD for my root partition and use a HDD under `/data/` and use system links in my home directory for file heavy directories such as:

`/data/home/user/Documents` > linked to `/home/user/Documents` 
`/data/home/user/Downloads` > linked to `/home/user/Downloads` 
etc.

In Ubuntu 17.10, GNOME does not follow these system links when indexing files for GNOME Search.  It only seems to index files/dirs which are located below `/home/user/`.

Screenshot:

[image: screnshot search settings]

I'm trying to figure out how to index files in other directories, so they show up in GNOME Search.  I would assume I would be able to add custom directories within the search settings. I've also been looking around in `dconf` but cannot find anything.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have just installed ubuntu 18.04 and this seems like a really bad implementation

Answer (score 3):

This should help you:

```
gsettings get org.freedesktop.Tracker.Miner.Files index-recursive-directories
gsettings get org.freedesktop.Tracker.Miner.Files index-single-directories
```

On GUI you can edit them with `dconf-editor`.

Did you try activating this?

```
gsettings set org.freedesktop.Tracker.Miner.Files index-removable-devices true
```

Answer (score 3):

Heh, actually the configuration wizard does exist, but by default it's not installed by Ubuntu (as of 17.10). You have to install "tracker" and maybe a couple other applets (?), look for it in synaptic.

Comment: I installed  the `tracker-miner-fs` package, and it pulled in everything I needed.

Comment: `sudo apt install tracker` also fixed this for me on Ubuntu 18.04 (tracker-miner-fs is a depencency and was installed as well).

Answer (score 0):

Another piece of the problem: Gnome Shell doesn't include results from drives other than the one your home directory is on.  So `tracker` may find your files, and Gnome will still ignore them.

You'll need to bind (rather than symlink) the directory into your home directory:

```
cd ~/
mkdir ./searchdirectory
sudo mount --bind /some/directory ./searchdirectory
```

or make it permanent with an fstab entry:

```
/some/directory /home/youruser/searchdirectory none bind 0 0
```

See this for more details:
https://superuser.com/questions/1260226/gnome-activities-search-does-not-show-most-files

And you'll probably need to do a `tracker reset -f DIR_NAME` to pick up the changes.